# How to replace characters in a spliced list?

Tags: python, splice

My code right now is very simple

```
sentence = input("Input a sentence: ")
print(sentence[::2])
```

My goal is to instead of having the spliced list replace the characters with nothing it will replace with another character like 'A'

Some things I've tried are

```
print(sentence[::2].replace("A", "B")
print(sentence[::2], sep = "A")
print(sentence[::2], "A")
```

Comment: This is not possible without creating a new string.

Comment: How would i do this with creating a new string?

Comment: `print("A".join(sentence[::2]))`

Answer (score 1):

One solution with `print`:

```
s = 'test'
print(*s[::2], sep='A', end='\n' if len(s) % 2 else 'A\n')
```

Prints:

```
tAsA
```

---

If `s='tes'`:

```
tAs
```

Comment: Nice use of end, op might want to use `os.linesep` instead of `\n` but that will probably be overkill

Answer (score 0):

You have the right idea with `sep`, but the wrong function.

- extract alternate characters with [::2]
- convert to a list of individual chars
- `join` them with the desired separator, `A`

Step by step:

```
>>> s = "Hello, world"
>>> s[::2]
'Hlo ol'
>>> list(s[::2])
['H', 'l', 'o', ' ', 'o', 'l']
>>> 'A'.join(list(s[::2]))
'HAlAoA AoAl'
```

Q.E.D.

Thanks to kaya3 for the bug catching.  Kludge solution:

```
>>> new = 'A'.join(list(s[::2]))
>>> if len(new) < len(s):
...     new += 'A'
... 
>>> new
'HAlAoA AoAlA'
>>>
```

Comment: Note that the `d` at the end has been lost instead of converted to `A`.

Answer (score 0):

The `join` method almost does this, but fails on even-lengthed strings:

```py
>>> 'A'.join('hello'[::2])
'hAlAo'
>>> 'A'.join('test'[::2])
'tAs'
```

To solve this we can add on an extra `A` if the length is even:

```py
def replace_alternating(s, sep):
    result = sep.join(s[::2])
    if len(s) % 2 == 0:
        result += sep
    return result
```

Here's an alternative solution using a regex to replace pairs of characters:

```py
>>> re.sub('(.).', r'\1A', 'hello')
'hAlAo'
>>> re.sub('(.).', r'\1A', 'test')
'tAsA'
```